# How to use search multiple record for IN condition with different spellings in DB2

Tags: sql, join, select, db2

I make little steps forward in my SQL knowing.
Now i have a problem and hope you'd help me.

I wanted to make an select on a table which shows me all records which are available several times (in different spellings)
Like:
abcd123 AND ABCD123 AND ABcd123 ...

```
db2 "select * from table where row in (select row from table GROUP BY row HAVING (COUNT(row) > 1)) order by row"
```

e.g:

```
db2 "select * from table where surname in (select surname from table GROUP BY surname HAVING (COUNT(surname) > 1)) order by surname"
```

the code above shows me the records which are available several times in the same spelling like SMITH AND SMITH AND SMITH, but not in different spellings like SMITH AND Smith AND smith AND SMith AND SmitH

Please help me.
(I can not make JOINS. It's actualy not in my knowing)

Thanks for help.

Comment: This is potentially a very complicated problem.  Perhaps `soundex()` can help.  Or Levenshtein distance.  Or something else.

Answer (score 1):

If your only concern is capitalization, then use `lower()` or `upper()`:

```
select t.*
from table
where lower(t.surname) in (select lower(t2.surname)
                           from table t2
                           group by lower(surname) 
                           having count(*) > 1
                          )
order by surname;
```

If you are concerned about other potential misspellings, then the problem is quite complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `UPPER()` function to your comparison

```
select * from table
where UPPER(surname) in (
   select   UPPER(surname) from table
   GROUP BY UPPER(surname)
   HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
) order by surname
```

Comment: Very nice. This Works many thanks. But now its not sorted by surname
Now its e.g:
SMITH
smith
Alan
SmitH

do you have a tipp?
And i need it as unix function like
"print -n "\\033[1;31mTable:\\033[0m ";read var1; print -n "\\033[1;31mRow:\\033[0m ";read var2; db2 "select * from $var1 where $var2 in (select $var2 from $var1 GROUP BY surname HAVING (COUNT($var2) > 1)) order by $var2" \r"

var2=surname
Can u help here also?
thanks a lot :)

Comment: My code was sorted by surname. If your is not, you were not running the same code!  Maybe best to ask your followup question in a new stack overflow queston

Comment: thanks a lot. i will test the sort and ask a new question